# error: Jquery form validate plug is appending duplicate error messages per field in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, error-handling, jquery-validate

In my form I am using [jquery form validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)  to validate a form. But the problem is that error messages are displaying multiple times below every field. As you see on the screen shot below.
This is working correctly in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

[image].

I found this error is occurring when I am using field `name="id"`

```
<input name="id" class=""/>
```

The following code I am using

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$("#form").validate({

    rules : {
        "id":{
            required:true,
            digits:true
        },

        "user_login":{
            required:true
        },

        "user_pass":{
            required:true
        }
        },
   messages: {
        "id":{
            required: "This field is required"
        },

        "user_login":{
            required: "This field is required"
        },

        "user_pass":{
            required: "This field is required"
        }
        },
   submitHandler: function(form){
        var formData = $('#form').serialize();
            $('#form').unbind("submit"); // fix for IE
            $.ajax({
                url: "",
                data:formData,
                type:"POST",
                error: function(error){
                },
                success: function(data) {
                }
            });
        return false;
      });
});
```

How can I avoid appending multiple error messages per field.

Edit: My HTML code is

```
<form id="form" name="" method="POST" action="">
<ul class="formstyle">
    <li>
        <label>Id</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" class="" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>User Login</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_login" class="" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>User Pass</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_pass" class="" />
    </li>    
    <li>
            <input type="submit"/>
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use id as the id or name of anything, there is too much that uses id as the identifier in some scripts. Could be causing a conflict

Comment: @darkveloper: I am trying to build small MVC framework, so that i am using mysql table column name as name in form element.

Comment: oh well then that makes it okay. It STILL could be the problem. Maybe try changing that just to try it in case I'm right. Also, if you're adding the class="required" to your fields, the plugin is already generating the message, so don't add your own custom messages with the class names, use one or the other.

Comment: Then you should give the form name/ids some kind of identifier... form_id or so. Using Id is only going to give problems. Could you paste the HTML? :)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/odijez/edit#javascript,html. I have tried this with name="id" and its working fine, seems you have any other issue ....

Comment: Can you put whole code here ?

Comment: @Marco Johnanesen: I am editing my question ... pasting HTML code.

Comment: @dev: did u tried with firefox ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/odijez/4/edit , updated and found working again ....

Comment: @Dev: thank you .. i though problem is in my css .. i will check my css..

Comment: Hi All, Currently I'm facing the same issue as mentioned in the question above. I'm using the latest jquery version: v1.11.3 & validate.min.js as v1.13.1. Still i'm getting the same issue. Plz help. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this done working.

```
Problem is with jQuery version.
```

I am using jQuery version: v1.4.3 (not working)

The jQuery version validation plug in working with: v1.6.4 (working)

Comment: Absolutely, I still would not use "id" as the name, `name="id"`. At worst, it will conflict with a reserved word in certain browsers, and at best, it makes code troubleshooting/editing uncessarily confusing.

Comment: Hi All, Currently I'm facing the same issue as mentioned in the question above. I'm using the latest jquery version: v1.11.3 & validate.min.js as v1.13.1. Still i'm getting the same issue. Plz help. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

The same issue can happen when using a form inside a table tag like the one below:

```
<table width="600">
<form id="form" name="" method="POST" action="">
... (rest of the table elements)
</form>
</table>
```

To fix the issue, you need to give the table tag inside the form tags, like below:

```
<form id="form" name="" method="POST" action="">
<table width="600">
... (rest of the table elements)
</table>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is also true for `<form>` elements inside other things like `<div>`s or `<section>`s. The validate plugin looks for error wrappers inside the `<form>`. If your error wrapper lives outside your `<form>` element, then the errors will stack on top of each other if the same error occurs more than once.